# Android Keyboard is not hiding on touch outside

Tags: android

I always thought the android keyboard would hide automatically when i touch outside of an `EditText`.
I have several text inputs in my application. Only the first has the tag

```
<requestFocus />
```

in the xml layout definition. I have no other implementations influencing the keyboard (or at least
i think i dont have any). The only maybe important thing is that i use `FragmentActivity` and `Fragment` from the support package only.

When i start my app the keyboard pops up correctly with the correct `EditText` in the focus. When i rotate my device my keyboard gets hidden (i really dont know why). When i rotate back it gets shown again. And when i click outside the `EditText` on the layout itself or on a button or something, the keyboard isnt hiding but i really want it to.

I thought there would be no additional coding needed for this purpose.

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: Yes and i read "When input focus moves into or out of an editable text field, Android shows or hides the input method (such as the on-screen keyboard) as appropriate." which is not the truth in my case.

Comment: `Note: Once the input method is visible, you should not programmatically hide it. The system hides the input method when the user finishes the task in the text field or the user can hide it with a system control (such as with the Back button).`

Comment: Yes i dont hide it programmatically. So there is no general functionallity for hiding the keyboard when the user touches outside of an edittext?

Comment: I'd try something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696791/745750

Comment: I dont like such hacky things. they dont feel like clean code for me. i would rather accept that i cant hide the keyboard automatically when user touches outside.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my root reason, it is because the host activity set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" , if remove it question will be solved, hope it works to you